# Azure Function - Add InvocationId with every log statement globally

Tags: c#, .net, logging, azure-functions, lifetime

I am writing an Azure function and I want to log the currently executing function's invocationId logged with the log message. I have a CustomLogger class utilizing the ILogger interface from dotnet. I have Transient, Scoped and Singleton lifetime objects - all adding some logs via the CustomLogger injected into them.  The CustomLogger had to be transient because it has to be injected into all type of Objects (based on lifetime). How do I get the invocationId in the logger class ? I dont want the user of CustomLogger to pass the invocationId everytime. Is it not possible ?

Comment: InvocationId is unique value that will be assigned by Azure function runtime, why you need to pass it from your code? You can "get" it from the function context, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.functioncontext.invocationid?view=azure-dotnet) page.

Comment: How do I log it with the log message in every class ? The logger does not have access to the current invocationId

Answer (score 0):

using this [reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function) we can add   InvocationId in the Azure Function.

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, context.InvocationId);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

- For more details refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210245/azure-functions-how-to-obtain-invocation-id-from-within-the-function) and [git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/395).

Comment: Is there a way I can get the invocationId (or the Context object) from within the CustomLogger class or using some global method ? I don't want to pass the InvocationId from the Run method to every place I need to log a message

Comment: @RKS if you want to use the `InvocationId` within a custom logger class or in multiple places without explicitly passing it as a parameter, you can make use of a  variable example `sam` to store the `InvocationId` and access it within your custom logger class or other methods.

Comment: Are you saying I store the InvocationId as a member inside the CustomLogger class object? The CustomLogger cannot store InvocationId as the Logger's lifetime can sometime span across multiple invocations. This is because some Singleton objects also use CustomLogger into themselves via Dependency injection.